# Ninject.MVC5 and Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

Tags: ninject

Using VS2013 Update 4 (update is very recent)

When attempting to add Ninject.MVC5 via NuGet the following error message is raised stating: Failed to add a reference to 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure'. Please make sure that it is in the Global Assembly Cache.

When adding from the NuGet command line this error is returned:

```
PM> install-package ninject.mvc5 version 3.2.0.0
Install-Package : No compatible project(s) found in the active solution.
At line:1 char:16
+ install-package <<<<  ninject.mvc5 version 3.2.0.0
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetNoCompatibleProjects,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I've gone through dozens of posts concerning issues with 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure' but none of them have resolved the issue.  I've removed the reference to it and added it back again still no go.  It is also set to copy local.

Here's a copy of my packages.config - this is a default MVC5 project with NOTHING added but the packages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS" version="3.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Elmah.MVC" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Fullcalendar" version="1.6.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.11.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moment.js" version="2.8.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap.Bootswatch.Cerulean" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Anyone else dealing with this issue?